# Determine the Widest Valley

Tags: code-golf, array

Imagine we get a slice of some mountainous region, this would result in a shape similar to this:

```
4                   _
3   _    _       __/ \
2  / \__/ \    _/     \_   /
1 /        \  /         \_/
0           \/
  12322223210012233343221112
```

As we can see, we can represent this (to a certain degree) with a sequence of integers.

For the purpose of this challenge we define a valley as a contiguous subsequence where the values initially are decreasing and from some point on they are increasing. More formally for a sequence \$(a_i)_{i=1}^n\$ a valley will be indices \$1 \leq s < r < t \leq n\$ for which the following holds:

- the valley's start and endpoint are the same: \$a_s = a_t\$
- the valley starts and ends once the region gets lower: \$a_s > a_{s+1} \land a_{t-1} < a_t\$
- the valley is not flat: \$a_s \neq a_r \land a_r \neq a_t\$
- the valley initially decreases: \$\forall i \in [s,r): a_i \geq a_{i+1}\$
- the valley will at some point increase: \$\forall j \in [r,t): a_j \leq a_{j+1}\$

Now we define the width of such a valley as the size of the indices \$[s,t]\$, ie. \$t-s+1\$.

### Challenge

Given a height-profile (sequence of non-negative integers), your task is to determine the width of the widest valley.

### Example

Given the height-profile `[1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,2,2,1,1,1,2]`, we can visualize it as before:

```
4                   _
3   _    _       __/ \
2  / \__/ \    _/     \_   /
1 /        \  /         \_/
0           \/
  12322223210012233343221112
    aaaaaa             ccccc
         bbbbbbbbb
```

Note how the second valley `[3,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,3]` does not extend further to the right because the left-most point is \$3\$ and not \$4\$. Furthermore we don't add the remaining two \$3\$s because we require that the endpoint is higher up than the second-last point.

Therefore the width of the widest valley is \$9\$.

## Rules

- Input will be a sequence of non-negative (sorry Dutch people) integers

  - you can assume that there is always at least one valley
- Output will be the size of the widest valley as defined above

## Testcases

```
[4,0,4] -> 3
[1,0,1,0,1] -> 3
[1,0,2,0,1,2] -> 4
[13,13,13,2,2,1,0,1,14,2,13,14] -> 4
[1,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,2,2,1,1,1,2] -> 9
[3,2,0,1,0,0,1,3] -> 4
```

Comment: Test case: `[3,2,0,1,0,0,1,3]`. All current answers return 8, by your definition I believe it should be 4.

Comment: Will the slope of the mountain ever be steeper than 1? (e.g. `[3,1,2,3]`)

Comment: @Zgarb: That's correct, yes. I added it to the testcases.

Comment: @Doorknob: There's nothing preventing that, yes. For example `[4,0,4]` would be such a case.

Comment: "_Input will be a sequence of non-negative (sorry Dutch people) integers_" Lol, as a Dutchman I giggled when I read this. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>120</s> <s>115</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> <s>152</s> 149 bytes

```python
lambda a:max(r-l+1for l,v in e(a)for r,w in e(a)if max(a[l+1:r]+[0])<v==w*any(s(a[l:i])[::-1]+s(a[i:r])==a[l:r]for i,_ in e(a)));e=enumerate;s=sorted
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7dDoIgFL7vKbiUpE2QmyiexFijhYtNsaFlPb1xIKu5Bmzn@z1cn8Olc2yq5WFqdHs6a6RFqx@Z3zQ5rTuPGnJH1iGTaQzQk3GGtkbg1FVwCq/yqlB4f5dyXGv3zHoQhFW4EmJDVQ7YBhuWEgSvoM2S49yG8c5I426t8Xowu172nR/Mebp66wZUZxUnBeEKE1SuPhwNXHx/eBY1Bgr/UUqSLgsnxSmHMZB86Q18MrL3BIHYGjEcTuYqOm/bfhvK9y9Sqlz0Qx4UaFnu5rE5qSk3vQA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>111</s> <s>108</s> <s>99</s> 97 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(o=(p,x)=>a.some(P=q=>(~x?x<0?i?q<P:q>P&&i++:i=0:q>=p)||(o=o<--x|q==P|q-p?o:x,P=q,0)))|-o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7LbsIwEEX3fEVWyBY2eXlDlEl@IXvEwqIBBQFjk6rywuqvp34EVFGlGlua8Zx7ry/yS47Hx6A@@R0/@ukEk4RGbm9SEQSimKF@HPHWkw40NOTbtKbO2qHVdVfppluvh82mGiBzAyhqrdNhzbmxGqCzmqsWK8OcmGWUUstxOuJ9xGu/veKZnMhesIyJA6VJmibl6m2Zu2W4/wFFgIoZEX@QksVTuIqGufCtexSLIgdERTF3XhlywuxLsKdn/it/925Vzh@M8nIp0Tt6xPsufkuE0Ii9nKYf)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                        // a[] = input array
  a.map(o =                 // initialize the output o to a non-numeric value
    (p, x) =>               // for each value p at position x in a[]:
    a.some(P =              //   initialize P to a non-numeric value
      q =>                  //   for each value q in a[]:
      (                     //     exit if something goes wrong:
        ~x ?                //       if x is not equal to -1:
          x < 0 ?           //         if x is negative:
            i ?             //           if we're in the increasing part:
              q < P         //             exit if q is less than P
            :               //           else:
              q > P && i++  //             increment i if q is greater than P
          :                 //         else:
            i = 0           //           initialize i to 0 (decreasing part)
        :                   //       else:
          q >= p            //         exit if q is greater than or equal to p
      ) || (                //     if we didn't exit:
        o =                 //       update the output o:
          o < --x |         //         decrement x; if o is less than x
          q == P |          //         or the last value is equal to the previous one
          q - p ?           //         or the last value is not equal to the first one
            o               //           leave o unchanged
          :                 //         else:
            x,              //           update o to x
        P = q,              //       update the previous value P to q
        0                   //       force this iteration to succeed
      )                     //
    )                       //   end of some()
  ) | -o                    // end of map(); return -o
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẆµIṠḟ0ṢƑaMIḢ)Ṁ‘
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrZDWz0f7lzwcMd8g4c7Fx2bmOjr@XDHIs2HOxseNcz4//9/tLGOkY6BjiEQg0jjWAA)**

Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrZDWz0f7lzwcMd8g4c7Fx2bmOjr@XDHIs2HOxseNcz4f3TP4fZHTWuOTnq4cwaQBiL3//@jo010DHRMYrl0og2BDDCGcYzAAkZgrrEOBBkBIUShoQmICRSEajbSgcgaQVkgVWD9YD4ImujA9BvCzDWGWgJRagwRMgZzQerBRpuANUKEgCpiAQ) (added two more test cases which I previously failed to fulfil).

#### How?

```
ẆµIṠḟ0ṢƑaMIḢ)Ṁ‘ - Link: list of integers
Ẇ               - all contiguous substrings
 µ          )   - for each substring, X:
  I             -   deltas
   Ṡ            -   sign (-ve:-1, 0:0, +ve:1)
    ḟ0          -   filter out zeros
       Ƒ        -   is invariant under:
      Ṣ         -     sort
         M      -   get maximal indices of X
        a       -   (vectorising) logical AND
          I     -   deltas
           Ḣ    -   head
             Ṁ  - maximum
              ‘ - increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 31 bytes

```
¡ãYÄÃrc k_ò< Åd_äa x}Ã®bZvÃrÔ+2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=oeNZxMNyYyBrX/I8IMVkX+RhIHh9w65iWnbDctQrMg==&input=W1s0LDAsNF0sClsxLDAsMSwwLDFdLApbMSwwLDIsMCwxLDJdLApbMTMsMTMsMTMsMiwyLDEsMCwxLDE0LDIsMTMsMTRdLApbMSwyLDMsMiwyLDIsMiwzLDIsMSwwLDAsMSwyLDIsMywzLDMsNCwzLDIsMiwxLDEsMSwyXSwKWzMsMiwwLDEsMCwwLDEsM11dCi1RbQ==)

Saved a 10 bytes by taking inspiration from Zgarb's Husk answer. I still think this can be improved, but I haven't found it yet.

Explanation:

```
¡ãYÄÃrc                            Get all segments
        k_           Ã             Remove ones where:
          ò<                        A non-increasing sub-segment
             Å                      Other than the first one
              d_äa x}               Has different heights
                      ®   Ã        For each remaining segment:
                       bZv          Get the second index of the first character
                           rÔ      Maximum
                             +2    Increase by 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 77 bytes

```
\d+
$*
M&!`\b(1+),((?!\1)(?!1+\2)1*,)+((?!\1)1*(?(3)\3|\2))*\1\b
1

O^`
\G,|$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUwxDsIwDNz9i0oFOYkH7GTv2AnxAQuFCgYWBsTYv6eJE2T7dPbd@fv6vT@PcsI1F30GmD1cz1PWDTk4QlwmZVeRg4pjTy6MG3tcMDqNexWcV9YNGOB2z6Ar7XMpiS6UgCvaGBPbBDhSb6nVLZwarceWEeqSDNYslrS9VaJ/mO1jHL@7Lx4) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
M&!`
```

List, rather than counting, overlapping matches.

```
\b(1+),
```

The valley's start is captured into `\1`. This must then not match again until the end. Since we don't capture the comma, this also prevents higher values from matching.

```
((?!\1)(?!1+\2)1*,)+
```

Match the decreasing values. The `(?!1+\2)` prevents the any pass through the loop from being greater than the previous. (The first time through `\2` isn't set so it fails to match trivially.) The capture includes the trailing comma as that's golfier.

```
((?!\1)1*(?(3)\3|\2))*
```

Match the increasing values. This time `((?3)\3|\2)` means that each match is required to be at least as long as the previous value, or the last decreasing capture the first time through the loop.

```
\1\b
```

Finally the end of the valley must be the same height as the start.

```
1
```

Delete the heights, leaving the commas. (This is slightly easier than counting the heights as some of them might be zero.)

```
O^`
```

Sort in reverse order i.e. most commas first.

```
\G,|$
```

Count the number of commas on the first line, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
→▲mΓ€fȯΛEtġ≤Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq1H8qKmxSPPQtv@P2iY9mrYp99zkR01r0k6sPzfbteTIwkedSwL///8fbaJjoGMSyxVtCKTBGMo2AvONQDxjHQgyAkKIMkMTEBMoCNFppAORNIKyQIrAusF8EDTRgWk3hJpqDLUBotI4FgA)

### Explanation

I use a similar algorithm as [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175345/32014).

```
→▲mΓ€fȯΛEtġ≤Q  Input is a list, say [3,1,0,1,1,0,2,3]
            Q  Nonempty slices: [[3],[1],[3,1],[0],...,[3,1,0,1,1,0,2,3]]
     f         Keep those that satisfy this:
                Argument is a slice, say [3,1,0,1,1,0,2]
          ġ≤    Cut into non-increasing pieces: [[3,1,0],[1,1,0],[2]]
         t      Drop first piece: [[1,1,0],[2]]
      ȯΛ        Each remaining piece
        E       has all elements equal: false, [1,1,0] has different elements
  m            Map over remaining slices:
                Argument is a slice, say [1,0,1,1]
   Γ            Break into head 1 and tail [0,1,1]
    €           Index of first occurrence of head in tail: 2
 ▲             Maximum: 2
→              Increment: 3
```